# DRY javascript with multiple text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have about 20 form text inputs. For each of them, I want to make sure they exist and apply the same logic to them, like so:

```
var title = $('#title')
if (title == '') {
     title.css({
       'background-color': 'rgba(230, 89, 78, 0.07)',
    }); 
};

<input type="text" id="title" />
```

How would I apply this 'in bulk' as opposed to re-writing this for each text input I have? Ideally, I would like to have a variable list with all the fields I need to do this for: `['title', 'company', 'copyright', ...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give them a common class (like `validate`) and then use `.each()`:

```
$('.validate').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.val()) {
        $this.removeClass('valid');
        $this.addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('invalid');
        $this.addClass('valid');
    }
});
```

From there, apply the styles with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

$("#title").css() will enumerate through every element, however, id's are meant to be unique on each page. I recommend adding a class 'title' and query by $(".title").css() instead.

```
<input id="title1" class="title" />
<input id="title2" class="title" />
<input id="title3" class="title" />

<script type="javascript">
  $(".title")each(function(){
      if(!$(this).val()){
        $(this).css({
          'background-color': 'rgba(230, 89, 78, 0.07)',
        }); 
      }
  });
</script>
```